# The greatest row per group - further combining the result set with left join with other related table in Hibernate - HQL. Is it possible?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle10g, hql, greatest-n-per-group

There two tables in my Oracle database `product` and `product_image`. They have one-to-many relationship from `product` to `product_image`. Therefore, the relationship can be mapped in Hibernate something like the following.

The product entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT", catalog = "", schema = "WAGAFASHIONDB")
public class Product  implements java.io.Serializable
{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "prodId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ProductImage> productImageSet; 
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_IMAGE", catalog = "", schema = "WAGAFASHIONDB")
public class ProductImage  implements java.io.Serializable
{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Product prodId;
}
```

I need to query that can fetch a list of rows with the maximum `prod_image_id` (primary key of the `prduct_image` table) from each group of products in the `product_image` table.

This was my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15851072/1391249). This can be done with the following SQL.

```
SELECT 
     pi.prod_image_id,
     pi.prod_id, pi.prod_image 
FROM 
     product_image pi 
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT 
          MAX(pi.prod_image_id) AS prod_image_id 
     FROM 
          product_image pi 
     GROUP BY 
          pi.prod_id
     ) prod_image 
ON pi.prod_image_id=prod_image.prod_image_id
```

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15855285/1391249) to that question corresponds to the following correct HQL.

```
SELECT 
    pi.prodImageId, 
    pi.prodId 
FROM 
    ProductImage pi 
WHERE 
    pi.prodImageId in (
    SELECT
         MAX(pis.prodImageId)
    FROM 
         Product p
    INNER JOIN 
         p.productImageSet pis
    GROUP BY 
         p.prodId
)
```

This brings the following result exactly as intended.

```
PROD_IMAGE_ID     PROD_ID      PROD_IMAGE
662               284          3562298873030291049_Winter.jpg
644               283          7551758088174802741_9392401244_SS_2505.jpg
595               124          298082252715152799_SS_5012.jpg
566               62           7826143854352037374_SS_5004-A.jpg
```

---

But what I actually need is that the result set retrieved by the above SQL/HQL needs to be combined with the `product` table with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so that it can retrieve each product from the `product` table regardless of their images in the `product_image` table something like the following.

```
PROD_IMAGE_ID     PROD_ID      PROD_IMAGE
662               284          3562298873030291049_Winter.jpg
644               283          7551758088174802741_9392401244_SS_2505.jpg
595               124          298082252715152799_SS_5012.jpg
 -                101                -
 -                81                 - 
566               62           7826143854352037374_SS_5004-A.jpg
```

This could be done by the following native SQL but doesn't seem possible with HQL which allows a subquery only in the `SELECT` and the `WHERE` clauses, a subquery in the `FROM` clause is disallowed in HQL.

```
SELECT 
     t.prod_image_id,
     p.prod_id,
     t.prod_image 
FROM
     product p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN(
     SELECT 
           pi.prod_image_id,
           pi.prod_id,
           pi.prod_image 
     FROM
           product_image pi 
     INNER JOIN (
           SELECT 
                MAX(pi.prod_image_id) AS prod_image_id 
           FROM 
                product_image pi
           GROUP BY 
                pi.prod_id
     ) prod_image 
     ON pi.prod_image_id=prod_image.prod_image_id
)t ON p.prod_id=t.prod_id ORDER BY p.prod_id DESC;
```

My Google search says this is not feasible with a single HQL statement. Is this possible somehow with HQL? Please confirm me.

Comment: using window (aka analytical) functions will be a lot more efficient than using a sub-select.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7581497) answer, the use of window functions is disallowed in Hibernate. HQL doesn't support window functions.

Comment: Ah, the "joys" of ORM tools. That's simply stupid, I know why I don't like ORMs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you can't use subqueries in from clause.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries

But you can use a separate query like:

```
select p 
from Product p 
where p.productImageSet is empty
```

to find the products that has no product image.

Comment: I'm now fetching the `Set<Product>` containing the corresponding images - `productImageSet` for each product and handling them on a view - JSP using JSTL stuff - iterating over the `Set` using a `<c:forEach>` loop, finding the maximum of `prodImageId` and so on. This could be somewhat a tedious job but seems more reasonable than other ways. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an Oracle view that implements your query that gives you what you want with a simple select in HQL.

Comment: Unfortunately, a view can not directly be queried through HQL. HQL is basically meant for querying entity classes that represent the relationships among tables in a database (as far as I know). Thanks.

Comment: Wow. So how does HQL know the difference between a view and a table?  Can't you model your view as just another table?

Comment: A view can be [accessed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4676162/1391249) via Hibernate through HQL with a separate entity class for that specific view. I didn't know about that and will give it a try later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having the same table relationship in MySQL. I'm currently trying to learn JPA. Accordingly, I'm using JPA 2.0 provided by Hibernate - version 4.2.7 final. The following JPQL,

```
select 
      p.prodId, 
      pi.productImageId, 
      p.prodName, 
      pi.prodImage 
from 
      Product p 
left join 
      p.productImageSet pi 
where 
      pi.productImageId in (
          select 
               max(productImageId) as productImageId 
          from  
               ProductImage 
          group by 
               prodId
   ) 
or pi.productImageId is null
order by p.prodId
```

and the corresponding criteria query,

```java
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple>criteriaQuery=criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
Metamodel metamodel=entityManager.getMetamodel();
EntityType<Product>entityType=metamodel.entity(Product.class);
Root<Product>root=criteriaQuery.from(entityType);
SetJoin<Product, ProductImage> join = root.join(Product_.productImageSet, JoinType.LEFT);

List<Selection<?>>selections=new ArrayList<Selection<?>>();
selections.add(root.get(Product_.prodId));
selections.add(root.get(Product_.prodName));
selections.add(join.get(ProductImage_.prodImage));
selections.add(join.get(ProductImage_.productImageId));
criteriaQuery.multiselect(selections);

Subquery<Long>subquery=criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
Root<ProductImage> subRoot = subquery.from(ProductImage.class);
subquery.select(criteriaBuilder.max(subRoot.get(ProductImage_.productImageId)));
subquery.groupBy(subRoot.get(ProductImage_.prodId).get(Product_.prodId));

Predicate []predicates=new Predicate[2];
predicates[0]=criteriaBuilder.in(join.get(ProductImage_.productImageId)).value(subquery);
predicates[1]=join.get(ProductImage_.productImageId).isNull();

criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.or(predicates));
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(Product_.prodId)));

TypedQuery<Tuple> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Tuple> tuples = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Both of them, JPQL and criteria query produce the following SQL query.

```
select
    product0_.prod_id as col_0_0_,
    productima1_.product_image_id as col_1_0_,
    product0_.prod_name as col_2_0_,
    productima1_.prod_image as col_3_0_ 
from
    social_networking.product product0_ 
left outer join
    social_networking.product_image productima1_ 
        on product0_.prod_id=productima1_.prod_id 
where
    productima1_.product_image_id in (
        select
            max(productima2_.product_image_id) 
        from
            social_networking.product_image productima2_ 
        group by
            productima2_.prod_id
    ) 
    or productima1_.product_image_id is null 
order by
    product0_.prod_id desc
```

resulting in fetching the desired result set as mentioned in the question - not in the way we can see in the usual RDBMS systems but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, if the query statement is slightly modified. Accordingly the following criteria query does what exactly is needed.

```java
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ProductUtils>criteriaQuery=criteriaBuilder.createQuery(ProductUtils.class);
Metamodel metamodel = entityManager.getMetamodel();
Root<Product> root = criteriaQuery.from(metamodel.entity(Product.class));

ListJoin<Product, ProductImage> join = root.join(Product_.productImageList, JoinType.LEFT);

List<Selection<?>>selections=new ArrayList<Selection<?>>();
selections.add(root.get(Product_.prodId));
selections.add(root.get(Product_.prodName));
selections.add(join.get(ProductImage_.prodImage));
selections.add(join.get(ProductImage_.productImageId));
criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.construct(ProductUtils.class, selections.toArray(new Selection[0])));

Subquery<Long> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
Root<ProductImage> prodImageRoot = subquery.from(metamodel.entity(ProductImage.class));
subquery.select(prodImageRoot.get(ProductImage_.productImageId));
subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root, prodImageRoot.get(ProductImage_.prodId)), criteriaBuilder.lessThan(join.get(ProductImage_.productImageId), prodImageRoot.get(ProductImage_.productImageId)));

criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery).not());
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(Product_.prodId)));
List<ProductUtils> list = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

This criteria query produces the following desired SQL query that does equally the same function which is needed as specified in the question.

```sql
select
    product0_.prod_id as col_0_0_,
    product0_.prod_name as col_1_0_,
    productima1_.prod_image as col_2_0_ ,
    productima1_.product_image_id as col_3_0_ 
from
    social_networking.product product0_ 
left outer join
    social_networking.product_image productima1_ 
        on product0_.prod_id=productima1_.prod_id 
where
    not (exists (select
        productima2_.product_image_id 
    from
        social_networking.product_image productima2_ 
    where
        product0_.prod_id=productima2_.prod_id 
        and productima1_.product_image_id<productima2_.product_image_id)) 
order by
    product0_.prod_id desc
```