# How to call oracle function using Hibernate criteria?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am new to Hibernate. I am building a Login Portal. We have used DB Function to encrypt User Password. It seems that using hibernate for complex queries/functions/procedures on existing databases is difficult.
Is it possible to write below queries using Hibernate criteria?
SQL Query 1 :

```sql
SELECT first_name
FROM user.emp_group
WHERE username = 'XXX'
    AND user.decrypt(password, 2) = 'YYYY';
```

SQL Query 2 :

```sql
SELECT a.DESC
    ,b.total
FROM user.STATUS a
    ,(
        SELECT STATUS
            ,count(*) total
        FROM user.emp
        GROUP BY STATUS
        ) b
WHERE a.TYPE = b.STATUS (+)
```

`User` is the schema name and decrypt is function name.

I also faced problem for getting data from views which was resolved by this Stackoverflow post. [How hibernate retrieve data from existing database view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676162/how-hibernate-retrieve-data-from-existing-database-view) 
Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native SQL with hibernate.

The way is something like this (for example):

```
String sql = "SELECT first_name, salary FROM EMPLOYEE";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
List data = query.list();

     for(Object object : data)
     {
        Map row = (Map)object;
        System.out.print("First Name: " + row.get("first_name")); 
        System.out.println(", Salary: " + row.get("salary")); 
     }
```

Comment: I use a code example from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm

Comment: Thanks.. I have tried native sql. It works. But since I am using hibernate, I wanted to use its api, specifically criteria api for building an application and maybe hql if using criteria is a headache.

Comment: But you are not able to call specific oracle function through criteria

Comment: You mean, there is no way to call a function using criteria api?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can use Expression.sql()
I've never used this before...but I think it'is the way. You can see the API here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Expression.html
The problem is that it's deprecated and you should use Restrictions.sqlRestriction(String)